# Removing empty Counter() objects from a list

Tags: python

I have a simple list of counters:

```
> counter_list
Counter({'Pig': 1}), Counter(), Counter({'Chicken': 3})
```

I cannot seem to find a simple way to remove the empty counter.

I have tried using

```
counter_list += Counter()
```

as per the documentation, with no luck.

```
del
```

Seems to only delete the contents of a counter, not the actual counter, and at best just creates more empty counter.

Any advice is appreciated, and apologies in advance for the future forehead-slapper.

Comment: Does order of elements matter?

Comment: No the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to build a new `counter_list`:

```
counter_list = [item for item in counter_list if item]
```

This works because an empty Counter is `Falsish`, while a non-empty Counter is `Truish`:

```
In [27]: bool(collections.Counter())
Out[27]: False

In [28]: bool(collections.Counter([1]))
Out[28]: True
```

Comment: If you just need to iterate over the `Counters`, skipping the empty ones, an alternative to the list comprehension would be to use `filter(None, counter_list)`. In Python 3, `filter` is a generator.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
counter_list[:] = (c for c in counter_list if c)
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generic answer which does not rely on the type of `item` being '`Falseish`' (but assumes it has a length returned sensibly by `len`)

```
counter_list = [item for item in counter_list if len(item) != 0]
```

Comment: But does require the item having a length :)

Comment: @JonClements Fair enough.